# How to treat uppercase and lowercase words the same in Python

Tags: python

Code:

```
str1 = input("Please enter a full sentence: ")
print("Thank you, You entered:" , str1)

str2 = input("Now please enter a word included in your sentence in anyway you like: ")

if str2 in str1:
    print("That word was found!")
else:
    print("Sorry, that word was not found")
```

I have done some research on forums etc and the only solutions i can find for this subject are converting words into uppercase/lowercase. I don't want to do it like that.

I want something that will ignore the fact that it is uppercase or lowercase and will assume it to be the same word, so when someone inputs a sentence it will automatically assume it t be the same word. For example: (Treat = treat, TREAT, TreAT etc). So it will essentially read the characters in the word and will ignore the uppercase/lowercase letters.

I do have something (string.ascii_letters) which i think might do it, but if anyone know any better way of doing it then that would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: why can't you compare `Treat.lower() == TREAT.lower()`?

Comment: Because i don't want to have to convert all the characters into upper/lower case. I'd rather keep all the words the same as the input but treated the same.

Comment: i have edited the original question which has my code, happy now? Now stop treating me like I'm mentally simple

Answer (score 2):

```
"Treat".lower()
```

will give you the lowercase value of a string. ie: `"treat"` in the above example

If you want it in a function.

```
def function_name(s):
    return s.lower()

print function_name("Treat")
```

Comment: ok, and how would i get it to do this automatically no matter what the input

Comment: @LukeP_8 I edited you can send string to the function.

Answer (score 2):

```
"DenvAAr".lower()
"Denvaar".lower()
"denvaar".lower()
```

All yield the same result: `denvaar`